# Android: How to callback from a library to the main app project?

Tags: android

i have a main app named App_1 then a custom library Lib_1

[Project View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDgJ7.jpg)

how can i callback or run a method from the **app_1** Main Activity when i clicked a button in **lib_1**? tia.

Comment: Please leave some sample code, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you have described, there is one main concept you need to learn first:

- the library is the dependency of the app

To set it up, add `library` to in build.gradle file of your app (find it in your app folder) in `dependencies` section - it may look like that:

```
dependencies {
  implementation project( ':library' )

  //other dependencies below (order doesn't really matter)
  (...)
}
```

**Then there are a few things which needs a little bit more explanation** - what do you mean by "button from library"? Have you created a custom button (check [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view) to check what it is)? Or do you mean that clicking a button in your app will run a function from library?

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface in **lib_1**, then in **app_1** create implementation of that interface and pass it to **lib_1**, whenever a button in **lib_1** is clicked call a method form that interface.

Answer (score 0):

Your app_1 can access lib_1's code(if you have setup the right relationship for the 2 modules), so you can define a callback method in your lib_1.
e.g. `public void onLibButtonClick(OnClickListener listenerFromApp)`. When you click the button on lib_1, you can call `listenerFromApp.onClick(View)`  to transfer click event.

You can also use `LocalBroadcastManager` related api to transfer event between modules(in one application). This should be reasonable sometime.